# AppWidget crashes launcher after configuration activity finish (Xiaomi and Huawei only)

Tags: android, android-appwidget, huawei-mobile-services, appwidgetprovider, xiaomi

I'm trying to display an AppWidget on device home. I can't figure why, only on Xiaomi and Huawei devices it doesn't work.

When I drag the widget on the home screen, it nicely open my config activity.
I close that activity using :

```
private void saveConfig() {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), 
        ConfigActivity.class.getName());

    Intent updateIntent = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);

    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

    updateIntent.setAction(ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, updateIntent);

    finish();
}
```

After that, the launcher seems buggy : screen become black, recent app drawer is open, I'm not on the same page I was...

There is nothing special in the LogCat.

Everything is fine one other devices like Samsung's or OnePlus.

Does someone had similar problem ?

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity
            android:name="com.######.presentation.activity.ConfigActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name=".presentation.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

       <activity
            android:name=".presentation.activity.LegalNoticeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

       <receiver
            android:name="com.######.provider.EnergyMixWidgetProvider"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".presentation.receiver.NotificationActionReceiver"/>

    <service android:name=".data.service.ListenerService" />
</application>
```

**appwidget_provider**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/app_widget_4"
     android:initialLayout="@layout/app_widget_4"
     android:minHeight="110dp"
     android:minWidth="250dp"
     android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
     android:resizeMode="horizontal"
     android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
     android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:configure="com.########.presentation.activity.ConfigActivity"/>
```

Any help would be gladly appreciate

**EDIT**
If I remove the config activity from the `android:configure` attribute of the apwidget-provider, appwidget **does appear** on the home screen.
It let me think that the problem is in the intent sent in the result of my config activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of widgets IDs. Try to change your code to:

In onCreate add

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
```

then do:

```
private void saveConfig() {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ConfigActivity.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

    Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
    updateIntent .putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, updateIntent);

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1, Entering  phone settings, finding Huawei desktop program, choosing  clear cache, and switching to the desktop.

Method 2, Have you installed a third-party mobile Butler app? Try uninstalling it. The main reason for icon restoration may be the theme. Try changing the theme, You can switch back to the default theme if you use a non self provided theme.

Method 3, Locking the screen without rotation or horizontal screen.

Method 4, Resetting Huawei desktop application.

- Click settings
- Click applications
- Click application management
- Click Huawei desktop
- Click storage
- Click delete data
- Click delete